# Randomizing content in Django using for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a different article from my database of 10 articles using Django to be random every time the page is refreshed. Each article consists of four pieces of information:

```
article.pubDate
article.author
article.heroImage
article.body
```

I've used a for loop `{% for article in object_list|slice:":1" %}` to get a single article, but I don't know if there's something like random or shuffle that I can tack onto my for loop.

**list.html**

```
{% for article in object_list|slice:":1" %}
    <div class="mainContent clearfix">
        <h1>Top 10 Video Games</h1>
        <p class="date">{{article.pubDate|date:"l, F j, Y" }}</p> | <a href="" class="author">{{article.author}}</a>
        <img src="{{article.heroImage}}" alt="" class="mediumImage">
        <p class="caption">{{article.body|truncatewords:"80"}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: do you need **only one** item? if so, why does your response have a list of items?

Comment: I basically need one random article each time the page reloads. I mentioned those four things above, was my attempt to clarify that those four pieces of info should relate to the one random article from the database.

Comment: did you see karthikr's answer? return only one object if you don't need more

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162629/django-shuffle-in-templates#answer-7162816

Answer (score 4):

How about fetching a random object from the view instead of the object list ?

Example

```
def myview(request):

    random_object = MyModel.objects.order_by('?').first() #or [0] if < django 1.6

    #Send this in the context..
```

And now reference this in the template instead of slicing a whole object list.

If you do need an object list, just do

```
random_list = MyModel.objects.order_by('?')
```

which would load a random list every time.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by). Note that this *could* be a little expensive though.

Comment: I'm confused what .py file to put your first snippet that you mentioned and what I need to rename "myview" and "Mymodel" to.

Comment: Seriously? Do you have views named `myview`, etc? This was only an example. In your views.py file, whatever view method is sending the context into the template should be doing this

Comment: Still pretty new to Django, so I'm learning the terms. My first piece of clarification is "Would I put def myview(request): random_object = MyModel.objects.order_by('?').first() in models.py or views.py"

Comment: Sorry.  I did not mean to be harsh. In your view which would render the template showing the random queryset object  would have this code.